# What could be the cause of this error. Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried generating a build release for flutter and I got these errors. Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'. The code I used for generating build is `flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi`. The debug works perfectly.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion 29
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.abc.def"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
```

The code I used for generating build is `flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi`. The debug works perfectly.        // This is the main section that I've updated
// to get the release APK to build
buildTypes {
release {
// TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
// Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
}
}
}

```
flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:19.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.3'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you have followed up correctly all procedures in this [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android), then after you are sure you have followed up correctly then

Try this out:

`flutter clean`

`flutter build apk --debug`

`flutter build apk --profile`

`flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi`

suggestion:
if this doesn't help then add the full error which you are getting as well as both complete Gradle files
and instead of splitting apk use app bundle, for app bundle use:

`flutter build appbundle`

if this helps then please notify in comments

Comment: Gracias Jagadish

Comment: Welcome... @ClintonSang...if it helped please upvote

Answer (score -1):

run in your terminal

`flutter channel stable`

`flutter upgrade --force`

`flutter pub cache repair`

next,

`cd <YOUR APP FOLDER>`

`flutter clean`

**AND** create a seperate fluter project using `flutter create <app-name>`
and include the generated ios folder and android folder into your project (obviously you need to delete the current ios and android folders) . If you made changes into these folders **consider using version control**